# php shell_exec echo

Tags: php, echo, shell-exec

I'm working on interfacing a microcontroller with a lamp server. I am trying to run the command `echo -e -n "data \r" > /dev/ttyUSB0` using shell_exec in php but with no results. It works just fine from the command line. Doing a little experimenting, I discovered that `echo -e -n "1 \r"` actually echoes `-e -n 1`. Is there a reason it won't take the -e or -n options?
Here's my code:

```
    <?php
    shell_exec('echo -e -n "1 \r" > /dev/ttyUSB0');
    ?>
```

Comment: Why not use the PHP file functions?

Comment: I did not think of that. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using shell_exec and echo, why not use PHP's filesystem functions?

```
file_put_contents('/dev/ttyUSB0', "1 \r");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some other functions too, try this function maybe you get your answer.

```
exec(command, $output);
```

This function takes a command and assigns to $output an array where each element is a line of the generated output.

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same -e -n 1. I need echo to use the -e and -n options

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem, calling from php

```
php > echo shell_exec("echo -e aaa\tbbb");
-e aaa bbb
```

note, that output contains "-e", while I have expected that '*echo*' command will interpret *-e* as flag and would not send it to output.

After doing some investigation I came to following conclusion:

- when *exec* or *shell_exec* are called from php - new shell interpreter is launched.

  - php launches "**sh**".
  - When I was running on CentOS **sh** was a symlink to **bash**, and *exec("echo ...")* worked as I would have expected.
  - Now I am running **Ubuntu**. **sh** is a symlink to **dash**, not *bash*!
  - And final root cause - builtin *echo* command in **dash** does not have/understand '-e' flag, so it just forwards it to output

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it goes what worked for me in case someone else comes across with this as well.

Yesterday night I've messing around and struggling with this myself. For this to work, the command you need to use should start by calling the echo bin directly `/bin/echo...` instead of only `echo`.

Also don't forget to use single quote `/bin/echo...` instead of double quote to avoid PHP null byte detection error (this part you did correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running with -e, I was trying to change the password from a php

running this didnt work

```
exec("echo -e \"$pass\\n$pass\" | passwd $user");
```

It said passwords dont match. Checking the echo i saw that -e was includes as a part of the echoing so i changed it to

```
exec("echo \"$pass\\n$pass\" | passwd $user");
```

And then it worked.